# Wifi Router Intermittent No Internet

Tags: router, internet

- TP Link Archer A6 Wifi Router (present one)
- Linksys 09993 Wifi Router (old one)
- Win 10

I have had an ongoing problem for about 2 years and now on my 3rd wifi router. They all seem to work fine for a few weeks. Then the routers start with No Internet, progressing more frequently, daily sometimes and for longer periods of time, sometimes a whole day.  If I leave the power off to both the modem and router for a couple of hours and then power back on, the issue is usually resolved. Not always though.  Sometimes I have to wait till the next day.  Sometimes, like today, the router started connecting to the Internet after an hour or so with no intervention on my part, I don't think.  Been working fine all day since this morning.

I power off the cable modem and wifi router each night using the power button an a Belkin surge strip. Occasionally, like this morning, the amber LED on the router is on with no Internet.

I am able to connect a network cable to the modem and have Internet.

I am able to connect and log into the router's admin util by wifi and by network cable, but not able to connect to the Internet with the computer.

Troubleshooting

- I cycle the power on and of, waiting 30 seconds between cycles (first the modem, then the router)
- Reset the router by pressing and holding the reset button for 15
  seconds and then releasing. Setting it back up.
- Replaced patch cable between router and modem.
- Checked router admin util and all seemed normal except it displayed No Internet
- Firmware up to date
- Released Renewed IPv4
- Changed the Primary and Secondary DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

I also checked "Clone Computer MAC Address" while the computer was connected by network cable to the router.  I then heard my phone alert for new message, meaning the router was now broadcasting Internet.  Could that have resolved the issue?

Router and modem are plugged into a Belkin surge strip which has a 4' long cord that plugs into a household 120 volt outlet.

Cable modem and Wi-Fi router are 2 separate devices connected by 3' long Cat 5 cable which has been replaced a couple of times.

I discovered too that if the TP Link failed, I could just switch in the Linksys and then visa versa. When the Linksys failed in a day or two, switch in the TP Link which in both cases immediately worked. Could this be malware?

Cable modem replaced a week ago by ISP.

Comment: I also checked "Use Computer MAC Address" while the computer was connected by network    .........  Are you using DHCP Reservation?  If so, you may have found the issue.  If not, then MAC address should not have any effect unless the MAC address was wrong for the network card.

Comment: Router's admin interface showing "No internet" suggests that the problem's between the router and your ISP. This being the 3rd router showing exactly same behavior suggests your home's power circuit might be wonky, power spikes or something like that damaging the equipment. Are you using an extension cable, if yes, have you tried another one? You're talking about modem and router - are those separate devices with separate internet access, if not, how exactly are they connected? Please edit your question to add new / updated info, don't reply in comments. Makes things easier and clearer :-)

Comment: Both modem and router are plugged into a Belkin surge strip which I noted earlier.

Comment: Cable modem and Wi-Fi router are 2 separate devices connected by Cat 5 cable.

Comment: Edit complete.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

are you using both of them in the same time? ( 2 cables to switch )

> I discovered too that if the TP Link failed, I could just switch in the Linksys and then visa versa. When the Linksys failed in a day or two, switch in the TP Link which in both cases immediately worked. Could this be malware?

- if **yes** you should not, or at least use the other one as **AP** with **NO dhcp** or with dhcp but different **Gateway** if it's from other subnet
- if **NO** when you change between them do you mean the WAN/DSL cable?
  in this case if it happend try put the cable back to the first router if it works after multiple tries this could be a PPP failed connection problem make sure you are using the right username and password from your cotract that the **ISP** gives you not the ones that they test the network with in first installation
- remember you can always go to your router logs and see what causes the problem
- and if you see (**DSL down** or **failed PPP connection**) you must call the **ISP** and explain the problem at least it could be a problem in their end

Answer (score 0):

I am only using one router at a time.
Router logs show 13 disassociateds on 2/4/23.
Since 2/4/23, the modem and router have been powered on 24/7 with NO Internet problems.  Prior to that date I would power off the modem and router at night.
Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).